# What is session management in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I want to know session management techniques in ASP.Net

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a good article on State Management in ASP.NET here:

> [INFO: ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307598)

This talks about both Application State and Session State, and the management thereof. What exactly are you concerned about? Perhaps adding a bit more context to the question would help.